# How to hide image button along with row header in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to hide a column in grid based on user role type

this is my c# code

```
 protected void gvBudget_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if (user == "1")
                {
                    ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("imgDelete");
                    imgBtn.Visible = false;
                }
            }
           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Info("Error in gvBudget_RowDataBound() " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

this is the html page

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grid_header_text">
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete" runat="server" CommandName="DEL" ImageUrl="~/Image/delete.gif"
      OnClientClick="if(confirm('Budget List Summary \n\n Selected record will be deleted please confirm')==false){event.returnValue=false;return false;}else{return true;}" TabIndex="18" ToolTip="Delete" />
     </ItemTemplate>

 <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid_header_text"></HeaderStyle>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

i am able to hide the button, but unable to hide the row header or the column.

[image]

Comment: that looks ok. you sure user = 1?

Comment: yes , i check it twice.

Comment: Hum, ok, perhaps try using style to hide. eg: imgBtn.Style("Display") = "none";

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message that you're logging, I am assuming that you have a GridView. If that is the case, couldn't something like this work?

gvBudget.Columns[0].Visible = false;

Comment: i used the method you have mentioned , by counting the gv column from 1 the delete is at 14 so it should be something like gvbudget.column[13].visible = false ;    right , but i am getting exception as the number of index is greater than the number mentioned  something likewise.

Comment: It would seem that index[13] is too much then. You can also(I think) use the column name to get the column index. Ex: gvbudget.Columns["columnName"].Visible

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is if we JUST hide the control, the column still renders. The key Rosetta stone here was that in fact your column control WAS hiding.

Say we have this:

[image]

And my code to hide the link button is say is this:

```
        Dim lb As LinkButton = gv.FindControl("btnLNK")
        lb.Visible = False
```

Then we get this:

[image]

So it DOES hide the control "in side" the column, but not the whole column.

So, you have to hide the cell, say like this:

```
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Cells(4).Visible = False
    End If
```

But note how his ONLY hide the data, not the header.

[image]

So we have to hide both header, and the data, say like this:

```
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Or
        e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
        e.Row.Cells(4).Visible = False
    End If
```

And we get this:
[image]